# Python 3: How can I get os.getcwd() to play nice with re.sub()?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to replace some content in a file with the current working directory using `python 3.3`. I have:

```
def ReplaceInFile(filename, replaceRegEx, replaceWithRegEx):
    ''' Open a file and use a re.sub to replace content within it in place '''
    with fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = re.sub(replaceRegEx, replaceWithRegEx, line)
            #sys.stdout.write (line)
            print(line, end='')
```

and I am using it like so:

```
ReplaceInFile(r'Path\To\File.iss', r'(#define RootDir\s+)(.+)', r'\g<1>' + os.getcwd())
```

Unfortunately for me, my path is C:\Tkbt\Launch, so the substitution that I get is:

```
#define RootDir C:  kbt\Launch
```

i.e. it's interpreting `\t` as tab.

So it looks to me like I need to tell python to double escape everything from `os.getcwd()`. I thought maybe `.decode('unicode_escape')` might be the answer but it is not. Can anybody help me out?

I'm hoping there's a solution that isn't "find replace each `'\'` with `'\\'`".

Comment: It's more than just os.getcwd() - it's any path. re.escape() also doesn't work because it escapes the ':' - C\:\Tkbt\Launch

Comment: Can't you use `/` instead of \ ?

Comment: @fp: `os.getcwd()` returns paths with backslashes. This is not about path literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to resort to `.replace('\\', '\\\\')` I am afraid, that's the *only* option you have to make this work.

- Using encoding to `unicode_escape` then decode again from ASCII would have been nice, if it worked:

  ```
  replacepattern = r'\g<1>' + os.getcwd().encode('unicode_escape').decode('ascii')
  ```

  This does the right thing with paths:

  ```
  >>> print(re.sub(r'(#define RootDir\s+)(.+)', r'\g<1>' + r'C:\Path\to\File.iss'.encode('unicode_escape').decode('ascii'), '#define Root
  #define RootDir C:\Path\to\File.iss
  ```

  but not with existing non-ASCII characters because `re.sub()` does not process `\u` or `\x` escapes.
- Don't use [`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape special characters in a string, that escapes a little too much:

  ```
  >>> print(re.sub(r'(#define RootDir\s+)(.+)', r'\g<1>' + re.escape(r'C:\Path\To\File.iss'), '#define RootDir foo/bar/baz'))
  #define RootDir C\:\Path\To\File\.iss
  ```

  note the `\:` there.

Only `.replace()` results in a working replacement pattern, including non-ASCII characters:

```
>>> print(re.sub(r'(#define RootDir\s+)(.+)', r'\g<1>' + 'C:\\Path\\To\\File-with-non-
ASCII-\xef.iss'.replace('\\', '\\\\'), '#define Root
#define RootDir C:\Path\To\File-with-non-ASCII-ï.iss
```

Comment: Urgle; `re.sub()` promises to interpret all escape codes, but `\xab` and `\uabcd` are not interpreted.